# Add or subtract a number from the names of all the files in a directory

Tags: bash, filenames, rename, arithmetic

I have a number of `png` and `jpg` files whose names are numbers, e.g.`0100.png`, in a directory,

- How can I add `1` to their names, for example, to get `0002.png` and `0003.png` from `0001.png` and `0002.png` respectively, without overwriting?
- How can I subtract `2` from their names, so that `0100.png` will not become `098.png` but `0098.png` instead?

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770060/subtracting-a-number-from-the-names-of-all-the-files-in-a-directory, but more difficult here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably end up using temporary directory in this case:

```
for file in [[:digit:]]*.png; do
    echo mv $file tmp/$(printf %04d $((10#${file%.png}+1))).png
done
```

The important part is `10#N` which forces bash to interpret `000N` as just `N`, otherwise leading zeros denotes octal numbers.

For example:

```
$ touch 0001.png 0002.png 0010.png 0020.png 0100.png 0200.png
$ for file in [[:digit:]]*.png; do echo mv $file tmp/$(printf %04d $((10#${file%.png}-1))).png; done
mv 0001.png tmp/0000.png
mv 0002.png tmp/0001.png
mv 0010.png tmp/0009.png
mv 0020.png tmp/0019.png
mv 0100.png tmp/0099.png
mv 0200.png tmp/0199.png
```

Comment: So just run this command two times changing `png`->`jpg`, or store extension in variable with `ext=${file/*./}` or add additional loop over all different extensions...

Comment: BTW, in `zsh` under default settings you don't need to set base for numbers. Also it is simpler to strip extension from file so expression for new filename become `tmp/$(printf %04d $(($file:r-1))).png`

Comment: Is the `tmp` dir under current dir? I run your command, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Tim Yes in my case `tmp` is in current directory, so at the beginning `mkdir tmp` is need and at the end `mv tmp/* .; rm -r tmp`. Of course you can use `/tmp` (or whatever) as well, I assume you will modify such details anyway so don't even include this to the answer. And of course there is `echo` at the beginning of the line which should be removed if you like what you see on the screen, I hope it is obvious...

Comment: I created a dir tmp under the current one, but still it is empty.

Comment: I found that without `echo`, it will work. Does `echo` not run the command following it?

Comment: @Tim I included `echo` just for your safety to not rename/remove important files after copy-paste of untested code. `echo` at the beginning of the line just prints everything after command and parameter substitution + arithmetic evaluation, but do not run the code.

Answer (score 2):

**The solution for (1)**

Sort the files according to their numbers and start renaming with the one with the highest number. That makes collisions impossible.

```
ls *.png | sort -rn | while read ...; do ... mv ...; done
```

**The solution for (2)**

Determine the number of digits (if it not the same for all files) and then use `printf` for keeping that length:

```
printf %04d.png 98
0098.png
```

Comment: Can we automate the process?

Comment: Thanks, but what are `...`? Can we also add and subtract a number?

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl's [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename) :

-2 :

```
$ rename -n 's@\b\d+\b@sprintf("%04d", $& - 2)@e'  0100.png
0100.png -> 0098.png
```

+1 :

```
$ rename -n 's@\b\d+\b@sprintf("%04d", $& + 1)@e'  0001.png 0002.png
0001.png -> 0002.png
0002.png -> 0003.png
```

You can remove the `-n` (dry-run mode switch) when your tests become valids.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: How do these work - without an intermediate temporary file?

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, I just get `0001.png not renamed: 0002.png already exists`