# Meaning of `10#N`

Tags: bash

[Jimmij wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167866/674):

> I would probably end up using temporary directory in this case:
>
> ```
> for file in [[:digit:]]*.png; do
>     echo mv $file tmp/$(printf %04d $((10#${file%.png}+1))).png
> done
> ```
>
> **The important part is `10#N` which forces bash to interpret `000N` as
>   just `N`, otherwise leading zeros denotes octal numbers.**

Is `10#N` part of arithmetic expansion, or something else?

Is this mentioned in the Bash manual or POSIX specification? I don't find it.

Comment: Who do we poke to fix the syntax highlighter?

Comment: @OrangeDog https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`10#N` or a general form `[base#]n` where `2 <= base <= 64` will interpret `n` as the number in that base.

The `bash` manual, section [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) mentioned this.

Note that this feature is not specified by POSIX, only available in `bash`, `ksh` and its derivatives, `zsh` with base between 2 and 36.

Answer (score 8):

From the Arithmetic Evaluation section of the [bash manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash),

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading 0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used. The digits greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, @, and _, in that order. If base is less than or equal to 36, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is in the `man bash` Inside `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION`:

```
LESS=+/'\[base#\]n,' man bash
```

> Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base.